# How do I fill a shape with a texture in Libgdx?

Tags: opengl, java, textures, libgdx

I am making a 2D racing game. I want to fill the area of the ground object with a texture. I have the shapes of the ground (a Box2D shape). If I make images of the ground with textures, it uses a lot of RAM, so I instead want to fill the shapes with copies of a small texture.

Comment: It depends a bit on how you want to fill it, if you just want to slap a texture on a shape look into PolygonSprite, PolygonSpriteBatch and PolygonRegion.

Comment: I want the texture to be repeated in the shape .